# Как оптимизировать алгоритм для нахождения максимальной грузоподъемности?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть задача из [codeforce](https://codeforces.com/contest/3/problem/B).

Суть в том, что у нас есть грузовик с возможностью перевозить v предметов. Всего два типа предметов: байдарки (тип 1) и катамараны (тип 2). Каждый объект обладает своим весом p. Необходимо найти максимальную  грузоподъемность набора.

Например:

```
3 2
1 11
2 20
1 10
```

Ответ тут будет:

```
21
1 3
```

Я решил реализовать такую идею. У меня есть объект - `Target(type, weight, index)`. Массив из таких объектов я сортирую, потом прохожусь по отсортированному массиву и пытаюсь сделать три суммы:

1. Только для байдарок
2. Только для катамарана
3. Смешанные

Понятное дело, что сумма накладывается в ограничение грузоподъемности.

```
 private static void solve() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int weight = input.nextInt();
 
        List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<>();
 
        String first = "";
        int firstSum = 0;
        int firstLoad = 0;
 
        String second = "";
        int secondSum = 0;
        int secondLoad = 0;
 
        String third = "";
        int thirdSum = 0;
        int thirdLoad = 0;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Target target = new Target(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt(), i + 1);
            targets.add(target);
        }
 
        Collections.sort(targets);
 
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // First case
            if (targets.get(i).type == 1 && firstLoad + 1 <= weight) {
                firstSum += targets.get(i).weight;
                firstLoad += 1;
                first += targets.get(i).index + " ";
            }
 
            // Second case
            if (targets.get(i).type == 2 && secondLoad + 2 <= weight) {
                secondSum += targets.get(i).weight;
                secondLoad += 2;
                second += targets.get(i).index + " ";
            }
 
            // Mixed case
            if (thirdLoad + targets.get(i).type <= weight) {
                thirdSum += targets.get(i).weight;
                thirdLoad += targets.get(i).type;
                third += targets.get(i).index + " ";
            }
        }
        
        int result = Math.max(firstSum, Math.max(secondSum, thirdSum));
        System.out.println(result);
 
        if (result == firstSum) {
            System.out.println(first);
        } else if (result == secondSum) {
            System.out.println(second);
        } else {
            System.out.println(third);
        }
    }
```

Но данное решение обламывается на таком тестовом наборе:

```
20 19
2 47
1 37
1 48
2 42
2 48
1 38
2 47
1 48
2 47
1 41
2 46
1 28
1 49
1 45
2 34
1 43
2 29
1 46
2 45
2 18
```

Я получаю

```
600
13 8 5 3 9 7 1 18 11 19 14 16 10
```

А должен:

```
630
13 8 3 18 14 16 10 6 2 5 9 7 1 11
```

Разница тут в таком наборе:

```
Вывод
600
    19  
 
Ответ
630
    6 2
```

Как это вылечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это в чистом виде задача о рюкзаке ([knapsack problem](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5)), где вместо веса - объём, вместо ценности - грузоподъёмность. Решается динамическим программированием.

Код [отсюда](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5)

```
int knapsack(int weights[], int costs[], int needed) {
    int n = weights.length;
    int dp[][] = new int[needed + 1][n + 1];
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int w = 1; w <= needed; w++) {
            if (weights[j-1] <= w) {
                dp[w][j] = Math.max(dp[w][j - 1], dp[w - weights[j-1]][j - 1] + costs[j-1]);
            } else {
                dp[w][j] = dp[w][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[needed][n];
}
```